# Java Unexpected Command

Tags: java

As we know that for running a Java Program we have to first compile it using **javac Main.java** Command and then we run it using **java Main** command but when I try **java Main.java** is also working without compiling the java file. How is it possible?[image]

I expected the **java Main.java** command to give error but it is not giving any error and it is running the progam without any problem.
(Use java Main.java command before compiling the file it would work)

Answer (score 0):

Java supports running a Java source file directly using the java command without compiling it explicitly using javac. This feature was introduced in JDK 11 as part of the "Launch Single-File Source-Code Programs".